# KeyError: 'Date' when it's spelled correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a program that reads a datarframe and does a line graph on its data, I'm trying to overlay a scatter of another dataframe in the same graph, but I'm getting the error `KeyError: 'Date` on the line  `ax3 = TMIN2015.plot.scatter(x ='Date', y='TMIN',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)` I'll add the code and how the dataframe csv file originally looks like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

def leaflet_plot_stations(binsize, hashid):

    df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinSize_d{}.csv'.format(binsize))

    station_locations_by_hash = df[df['hash'] == hashid]

    lons = station_locations_by_hash['LONGITUDE'].tolist()
    lats = station_locations_by_hash['LATITUDE'].tolist()

    #plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

    #plt.scatter(lons, lats, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)
    
    #---my code---
    #1. Read the documentation and familiarize yourself with the dataset, then write some python code which returns a line graph 
    #of the record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014. The area between the record 
    #high and record low temperatures for each day should be shaded.
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
    df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
    
    df2[(df2['Date'] > '2005-01-01') & (df2['Date'] < '2014-12-31')]
    #sorting by date to make the data reading easier
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Date")
    
    #groupyingby the min and max
    df2 = df2.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg([('TMIN','min'), ('TMAX','max')])
    
    #this other syntaxis is valid, but due to the version of the current library it causes an error, that's why I used the 
    #method above
    
    #df2.groupby('Date').agg(TMIN = ('Data_Value', 'min'), TMAX = ('Data_Value', 'max'))
    
    #reseting the index so I can use the dates further on
    df2 = df2.reset_index()
    
    #creating the line graph
    ax1 = df2.plot(x ='Date', y='TMIN', kind = 'line')
    ax2 = df2.plot(x ='Date', y='TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)

    y1 = df2['TMIN']
    y2 = df2['TMAX']
    
    #to calculate the position in scale
    ny = ((y2-np.min(y2))/(np.max(y2)-np.min(y2)))*(np.max(y1)-np.min(y1))+np.min(y1)
    
    #shading between spaces
    #ax1.fill_between(df2['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1<=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
    #ax1.fill_between(df2['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1>=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
    plt.fill_between(df2['TMIN'],df2['TMAX'], interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
    
    plt.xlabel('Year Interval')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature Frequency')
    plt.title('Record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014')

    
    #2. Overlay a scatter of the 2015 data for any points (highs and lows) for which the ten year record (2005-2014) record 
    #high or record low was broken in 2015.
    
    TMIN2015 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
    TMIN2015['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(TMIN2015['Date'])
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015[(TMIN2015['Date'] > '2015-01-01') & (TMIN2015['Date'] < '2015-12-31')]
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.sort_values(by="Date")
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg([('TMIN','min'), ('TMAX','max')])
    TMIN2015 = TMIN2015.reset_index()
    
    ax3 = TMIN2015.plot.scatter(x ='Date', y='TMIN',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)
    ax4 = TMIN2015.plot.scatter(x ='Date', y='TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)
    
    return plt.show()

leaflet_plot_stations(400,'fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89')
```

An example on how the table looks like without being modified in code:

|  | ID | Date | Element | Data_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USW00094889 | 2014-11-12 | TMAX | 22 |
| 1 | USC00208972 | 2009-04-29 | TMIN | 56 |
| 2 | USC00200032 | 2008-05-26 | TMAX | 278 |

Comment: Will you please add `print(TMIN2015.columns)` right before you plot? And send the output of that.

Comment: Index(['Date', 'TMIN', 'TMAX'], dtype='object'). Note that this is how it looks like with the whole code, including modifications on the dataframe.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but didn't encounter an error. Are you using the latest pandas version?  Also note that your example code is much too large. Try reproducing your issue with just some minimal code.  (PS: you probably want to use `>=`and `<=` in ` `TMIN2015 = TMIN2015[(TMIN2015['Date'] > '2015-01-01') & (TMIN2015['Date'] < '2015-12-31')]`)

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook, so it must be a recent version, I'm not entirely sure. Also, thanks a lot for the suggestion and your attempt. If you manage to find anything, I'll be here. I will also try to find something on my own, but I've tried for hours.